# Why some people say just "C+" instead of C++?

Tags: c++, history

In the past I have seem a couple of people say C+ (with just one plus). I always thought that such persons were "ignorant" cos the language is called C++ not C+.

However, I was watching a youtube video were a guy said that there was a language called C+ before C++ (or C+ changed its name to C++, it is not clear what the guy is saying in the video). Is this correct? I never heard of just C+ before, is there any language called C+? If there is such language, is such language related to C++?

Comment: Well, if there is, don't feel too bad about it. I've never heard of C+ either.

Comment: It looks like another thread when I discover the ignorant one is me.

Comment: Oh no, topic will be closed again....

Comment: If u click the close button your favorite baseball team will finish last in the division this season!

Comment: I dont see any reason whatsoever to close this Q.It is a valid Q, Don't close Q's because you don't like them, close them only if they don't fit in the SO policy.

Comment: Of course George Orwell fans just call it C double-plus

Comment: @Als I dont think those guys who voted read the question or if they do, probably have comprehension problems :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[C+/ABCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABCL/c+)** is not related to C++ in any way, It is an different and unrelated language which is younger than C++.

Comment: I never heard of this language, nice post.

Comment: According to the page you link to, it's actually *younger* than C++.

Comment: @ruakh: Corrected the typo.Mind plays funny games sometimes after a days hard work :)

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of it (and I've been around C++ for a long time now).
Bjarne Stroustrup doesn't mention it in *The Design and Evolution of
C++*_, and I guess he would know.  The language was originally called
“C with Classes”, but the name was changed to
“C++” long before the language got out of AT&T.  (There is
an ABCL/c+, but it has nothing to do with C++, and is much later.)